# Gnome Shell extensions not loading, no error message available

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I have two gnome-shell extensions that don't appear to be loading after upgrading to 3.24. In gnome-tweak-tool they have a warning sign icon with "Error loading extension", and nothing else. I tried using looking glass (`lg`), and it just says "Error", and that the extension "has not reported any errors".

How can I debug the extension to find out why exactly it's not loading?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the error in the systemd journal:

```
$ sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

Answer (score 21):

Just simply run this on terminal:

```
gnome-extensions-app
```

and enable it to make the extensions work.
Works perfectly with GNOME 40

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned on the [Github](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/#installation-from-source) page.

A Shell reload is required. Press `Alt+F2 r Enter` and the extension has to be enabled with `gnome-tweak-tool` or with `dconf`.

As mentioned on [Dash to Dock's](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) User reviews. Make sure you disable **Ubuntu Dock** if you are using this in Ubuntu, otherwise you are going to have conflicts.

To disable **Ubuntu Dock** type the following in terminal:

```
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: my problem is solved with your reload + open tweak to enable Extensions

Answer (score 5):

I also experienced the same error. I think I will like to state the procedures that I took to make mine to work, and then you can check to see if you got it wrong somewhere.

**Here are the steps**

First install the Gnome shell extensions package from the terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

And then reboot your system. After that, start GNOME Tweaks and you’ll find a few extensions installed. You can just toggle the button to start using an installed extension.

Next, go to GNOME Extensions website ([GNOME User Themes Extensions)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) and download the extension with the latest version (Although, I often prefer to download the version next to the latest version, since it may be more stable).

Extract the downloaded file to the **~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions** **(home/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions)** directory. You can press Ctrl + H to show hidden folders. Create the extensions folder if you don't have it yet.

Now restart GNOME Shell. Press Alt+F2 and enter r to restart GNOME Shell.

Restart GNOME Tweaks tool as well. You should see the manually installed GNOME extension in the Tweak tool now. You can configure or enable the newly installed extension here.

That's all

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Loging in without wayland works for me.

Answer (score 0):

My extension was not enabling. I just `log out` and `log in` back and ran this command.

```
gnome-extensions enable example@hammad.example.com
```

It worked in my case.